# SSRS Multi Parameter Report not working in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services

I have a report which has 2 Parameters both are multi select. It works fine in SSRS Reporting Manager and Report Builder but when I host in SharePoint and try to select multiparameter it doesn't do anything. Do we need to make some setting change in SharePoint to accept multiparameter or this is an issue with SSRS and SharePoint combination. 
Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Do you get some errors? I used multi-select in sharepoint report and it s working fine. Where do you read these values? Maybe the user has no permissions on the query to populate the select

Comment: NK SP, Nope, I dont get any errors, while I select the multi parameter and select apply the page just refreshes and does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

After you upload the report to the SharePoint library, go to the manage parameters and see if you find any errors there.